# Rails Association but method not available

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-associations

I am following the Treehouse tutorials on creating Rails App. My GitHub folder is: https://github.com/phanatuan/facebook

I have the User & the Statuses object, where I have set up the Associations for the two as follow:

- Status belongs_to User
- User has_many Statuses

However, I could not call the method `@status.user.email` to display the User Email in my views\statuses\show.html.erb.

Comment: Does your status actually have a user assigned?

Comment: Checking your code... I got some questions: You dont have a UsersController, how do you create them? How do you require an email for a user, or even a user for a status?

Comment: I create the user using the Devise gem. When the user registered, an email is required and stored in the database. I established the association using the **Status belongs_to User**. However, when I called up @Status.user, it returns as nil. That's what confused me.